# Cannot Debug in Real iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging

Code run just fine. I can debug in simulator. I am used to be able to debug in iPhone too. Code can be **built** for iPhone. However, I can't debug directly to iPhone.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CLog(@"Hello I am called"); //i put break point here and it's never reached
```

If I tried to debug to iphone the iphone will display the splash screen and then quit.

There is no log in debug area.

What should I do?
Additional note: work for my iphone doesn't work for my friends' iphone. Also the program is more laggy on my friends' phone (yes it can run you just can't debug there)

ios is ios5 on both phone 5.11 (mine)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behaviour if I've installed a development build over the top of an ad hoc build.  I believe the problem is that an entitlements file from the ad hoc build that disallows debugging remains, causing the problem.  I suggest deleting the application from your device, then trying again.

If this is the problem, I find there are several benefits to using a separate bundle ID for development/test/release builds.  It means you can have all three installed simultaneously on one device, and their user preferences etc. remain separate.  It also prevents problems like this from occurring.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. However I've changed the bundle id. Let me verify before checking this as answer.

Comment: I already delete the application from the device. Also the device ad hoc provisioning profile has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but maybe your iPhone is still running an ios version version before 3.0? This call is only used from 3.0 onward.

Comment: OP does mention the phone is running 5.1.1

Comment: As mentioned it was a long shot, also the version of phone/software was edited after my answer :-).